# iOS - Declaring 2D array with fixed column and unknown rows (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I want to declare a 2d array in which I know the number of columns I need, but want to add rows to each column as the program runs. I want the array to hold NSMutableDictionary objects. How would I do this?

UPDATE: 
made a 2d array but it crashes when calling objects:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < [resultSet  count]-1; ++i){
                    NSMutableDictionary *temp = (NSMutableDictionary *) [resultSet objectAtIndex:i];
                    if (temp == nil) break; // Break if nil
                    NSMutableDictionary * currentEntry = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                    //store the firstname, lastname, userid, starting and ending dates

                    [currentEntry setObject:[temp objectForKey:@"ticket_id"] forKey:@"ticket_id"];
                    [currentEntry setObject:[temp objectForKey:@"title"] forKey:@"title"];
                    [currentEntry setObject:[temp objectForKey:@"user_id"] forKey:@"user_id"];
                    [currentEntry setObject:[temp objectForKey:@"date_submitted"] forKey:@"date_submitted"];
                    [currentEntry setObject:[temp objectForKey:@"date_resolved"] forKey:@"date_resolved"];
                    [currentEntry setObject:[temp objectForKey:@"handled_by"] forKey:@"handled_by"];
                    [currentEntry setObject:[temp objectForKey:@"status"] forKey:@"status"];
                    [currentEntry setObject:[temp objectForKey:@"category"] forKey:@"category"];
                    [currentEntry setObject:[temp objectForKey:@"priority"] forKey:@"priority"];
                    [currentEntry setObject:[temp objectForKey:@"description"] forKey:@"description"];
                    [currentEntry setObject:[temp objectForKey:@"resolution"] forKey:@"resolution"];
                    //stored in db in enum as "school" this translates it to "campus"
                    //maintains backwards compatability with db and previous app versions
                    [currentEntry setObject:[temp objectForKey:@"location"] forKey:@"location"];
                    [currentEntry setObject:[temp objectForKey:@"date_modified"] forKey:@"date_modified"];
                    [currentEntry setObject:[temp objectForKey:@"room_no"] forKey:@"room_no"];

                    [currentEntry setObject:[temp objectForKey:@"submitter_name"] forKey:@"submitter_name"];
                    [currentEntry setObject:[temp objectForKey:@"submitter_surname"] forKey:@"submitter_surname"];

                    [currentEntry setObject:[temp objectForKey:@"item_type"] forKey:@"item_type"];
                    NSLog(@"ITEMS: %@", [currentEntry objectForKey:@"item_type"]);
                    int k = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++) {
                        if ([[currentEntry objectForKey:@"item_type"] isEqualToString:items[i]]) {
                            myArray[i] += 1;
                            k = i;
                        }
                    }
```

2D array declaration:

```
                    multiArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                  [NSMutableArray array],
                                  [NSMutableArray array],
                                  [NSMutableArray array],
                                  [NSMutableArray array],
                                  [NSMutableArray array],
                                  [NSMutableArray array],
                                  [NSMutableArray array],
                                  [NSMutableArray array],nil];
```

More Code:

```
                    if ([[currentEntry objectForKey:@"handled_by"] isEqualToString:@"unassigned"]) {
                        [currentEntry setObject:@"unassigned" forKey:@"handler_name"];
                        [currentEntry setObject:@"" forKey:@"handler_surname"];
                    }
                    else {
                        [currentEntry setObject:[temp objectForKey:@"handler_name"] forKey:@"handler_name"];
                        [currentEntry setObject:[temp objectForKey:@"handler_surname"] forKey:@"handler_surname"];
                        //}
                    }
```

Adding objects to 2d and 1d array

```
if([tabbarData.ticketListViewMode isEqualToString:@"Maintenance"] ||
                       [tabbarData.ticketListViewMode isEqualToString:@"Cleaning"] ||
                       [tabbarData.ticketListViewMode isEqualToString:@"I.T."] ||
                       [tabbarData.ticketListViewMode isEqualToString:@"viewAll"]){
                        LoginData *login = [self dataObject];
                        if([login.userRole isEqualToString:@"MR"] || [login.userRole isEqualToString:@"AS"] ||
                           ([login.category isEqualToString:[temp objectForKey:@"category"]] &&
                            ([login.userRole isEqualToString:@"CM"] || [login.userRole isEqualToString:@"UR"]))){
                               [ticketList addObject:currentEntry];
                               [ticketInformation addObject: currentEntry];
                               [[multiArray objectAtIndex:0] addObject:currentEntry];
                           }
                    }
                    else{
                        [ticketList addObject:currentEntry];
                        [ticketInformation addObject: currentEntry];
                        [[multiArray objectAtIndex:0] addObject: currentEntry];
                    }
                }
```

**This crashes**

```
NSLog(@"word: %@", [[[multiArray objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:5] objectForKey:@"priority"]);
```

**This does not crash**

```
   NSLog(@"word1: %@", [[ticketList objectAtIndex:5] objectForKey:@"priority"]);
```

Comment: An array holding arrays holding dictionaries. Sounds very OOP. Show us what you've tried so far

Comment: updated question

Comment: Please check currentEntry object before adding to array, if that is null.

Comment: I have a 1d array and it adds to it fine.

Comment: How I add to 1d array vs 2d.
[ticketInformation addObject: currentEntry];
[[multiArray objectAtIndex:0] addObject: currentEntry];

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your are adding `currentEntry` object at `index 1` of the `multiArray` and then accessing it at `index 0`.

I ran your code and it worked fine:

```
NSArray *multiArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                              [NSMutableArray array],
                              [NSMutableArray array],
                              [NSMutableArray array],
                              [NSMutableArray array],
                              [NSMutableArray array],nil];

[[multiArray objectAtIndex:0] addObject:currentEntry];

NSLog(@"currentEntry Object: %@",[[multiArray objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0]);
```

Also, make sure `currentEntry` isn't null before adding it to the `mutableArray`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: [[multiArray objectAtIndex:0] addObject: currentEntry]; I tried to add it like this and still get the error

Comment: Looking at the error you updated in your question. It seems like you are accessing an out of bound object in an array. Maybe you are accessing currentEntry at index 1 instead of index 0.

Comment: When you add an object in an array, it's added at index 0 by default. I print out the object at index 0 and it's working fine.

Comment: posted entire loop and cleaned up question.

Comment: Debug your code thoroughly and see if `index 5` exists in the `subArray` of `multiArray`. There is a logical error in your code.

`ticketList` has 6 objects that's why you can access it at `index 5` whereas `multiArray[0]` doesn't have 6 objects to access an object at `index 5`.

Comment: I think when i add more than one object to a certain column it overwrites the row instead of creating a new index, because calling index [0][0] works but nothing else. How can i fix this?

Comment: It's not possible that it overwrites instead of adding at new index. Check if you are declaring `multiArray` again and again, this might be the reason it never increases its count.

Comment: I just looped through it and it overwrites it each time.

Comment: I show how I declare multiArray and how i call it, all this is only done once.

Comment: You are declaring `multiArray` in your `for loop`. Declare it on top, outside of the loop.

Comment: Haha. It happens sometimes.